# PineScript : Do not wait next candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have developed an external bot which clicks on the button "Sell Market" and "Buy Market" on Tradingview as soon as my Pinescript script displays (through plot) a signal to sell/buy. As my broker is connected to Tradingview, it makes real orders on my  broker (which is Tradovate btw).
In parallel, the Strategy Tester makes a order too as the exact same time.

With the option "On bar close" (in the "Fill orders" configuration) unchecked, I have exactly the same results on both sides (Strategy Tester on Tradingview and real market on Tradovate). So the Strategy Tester and my clicks on the Tradingview buttons are synchrone. And the results are not good actually.

But when I activate the option "On bar close" on Tradingview, Tradingview opens and closes positions one candle earlier than Tradovate does. So it seems this option doesn't have any effect on the buttons "Sell Market" and "Buy Market" of Tradingview. And the Tradingview results are good !

So I would like to know if there is a way to enter the market one candle earlier and not to wait the next candle for real orders ?

Even if the option "process_orders_on_close = true" is in my strategy, the real orders are one candle late.

I also have tried this morning the option "calc_on_every_tick=true" with and without the "On bar close", it doesn't have any impact on the Strategy Tester, so I guess it won't have any impact on the real orders neither.

So I'm currently frustrated to be at one candle to be profitable... ^^
I would appreciate your help.

Thank you,